# Duplication/Updation of data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get the sum of the data for every 5 minutes.
I have 15 motes.
for ,suppose in the first 5 minutes only some motes are queried and in the next 5 minutes other some motes are queried.
Now,In the second 5 minutes I need the data of the motes which are not queried in that 5minutes also
ie.,in the first 5minutes moteid's 1,2,3,4,9,12,14 are queried and in the second  minutes moteid's 1,5,6,7,9,13,14 are queried.
In the second 5 minutes,I need the data to be updated for the one's which are not queried also.Is it possible to get the data from the previous 5 minutes

```
moteid2 | 28 | 2012-09-25 17:45:43 | | 
moteid4 | 65 | 2012-09-25 17:45:49 | | 
moteid3 | 66 | 2012-09-25 17:45:51 | | 
moteid6 | 25 | 2012-09-25 17:45:56 | | 
moteid5 | 29 | 2012-09-25 17:45:58 | | 
moteid7 | 30 | 2012-09-25 17:46:05 | | 
moteid4 | 95 | 2012-09-25 17:50:29 | | 
moteid6 | 56 | 2012-09-25 17:50:35 | | 
moteid5 | 58 | 2012-09-25 17:50:36 | | 
moteid4 | 126 | 2012-09-25 17:55:08 |
```

In the first 5 minutes moteid2, moteid3 are queried, but after that in the next 5minutes they are not queried. Even If they are not being queried i want the same previous queried value to be kept now.

Comment: I think you will need to show a sample of your data (create/insert) and the desired result.

Comment: moteid2   |  28 | 2012-09-25 17:45:43 |
| moteid4   |65 | 2012-09-25 17:45:49 |
| moteid3   |66 | 2012-09-25 17:45:51 |
| moteid6   |25 | 2012-09-25 17:45:56 |
| moteid5   |29 | 2012-09-25 17:45:58 |
| moteid7   |30 | 2012-09-25 17:46:05 |
| moteid4   |95 | 2012-09-25 17:50:29 |
| moteid6   |56 | 2012-09-25 17:50:35 |
| moteid5   |58 | 2012-09-25 17:50:36 |
| moteid4   |126 | 2012-09-25 17:55:08 |In the first 5 minutes moteid2,moteid3 are queried,but after that in the next 5minutes they are not queried.EvenIf they are not being queried i want the same previous queried value to be kept now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the table name is `motes`. In this case the following query displays all unique `motesid` for the records which present in the whole table but were not queried in last 5 minutes:

```
select distinct m.motesid
from motes m
where not exists (
    select *
    from motes m1
    where 
        m1.moteid = m.motesid and
        m1.date > SUBTIME(CURTIME(), '0:05:00')
)
```

Comment: Thankyou,What does m and m1 mean?

Comment: `m` and `m1` are aliases for `motes` table. Since this table is used twice (once in external query and once in internal one within `not exists`), we need to use aliases.

Comment: Actually my table name is Statistics.Will there be any problem if i use m and m1

Comment: select distinct m.IPAddress from Statistics3 m where not exists (select * from Statistics3 m1 where m1.IPAddress = m.IPAddress and m1.datetime > SUBTIME(CURTIME(), '0:05:00') );